# How do I stop myself from training to a point that I have no energy for rest of the day?

Tags: recovery, overtraining, programming

I've been training early morning for a while now. I go to the gym at seven in the morning, get out, and then immediately go to school.

However, I notice that after training, I barely have any energy for the school day. I feel like maybe I'm training too much.

How could I set reasonable limits to my training?

At the moment my program is to rotate between Rows-Deads-Squats-Bench with accesory work of overhead press every second session, with a frequency of two days between workouts.

Comment: What are you eating/drinking immediately after training? How are your sleep and stress levels?

Comment: Do you have to train before school? Some people are not good morning workout people. Everyone has a "good" time for working out.

Answer (score 3):

### Increase session frequency so you can decrease session volume.

Based on your question, you’re at 1 session per 3 days, which averages out to 2.33 session per week. Increasing this to 3 sessions per week and rearranging your exercise selection so that you’re doing the same work in 3 sessions instead of 2 will reduce your per-session volume by about 28.5% (each session is around 77.8% the original per-session volume, 1/.778 = 1.285). This reduction in volume should correspond to the reduction in per-session fatigue you’re looking for.